# Decrease label text size based on container width

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a sidebar with a display name and the problem is if the user name is too long it will go beyond the container. I tried to use Jquery FitText but it doesn't seem to do what i want unless i'm doing something wrong. Function to resize is always called even if i change browser window size and the container where the name is didn't change anything. Is there a way to make the text fit the container without going beyond it?

[image: Sidebar Display Name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible with pure CSS.

Here is a great article: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/.

**UPDATE**

The issue with using pure CSS is that the text will always fit the viewport. The following custom solution only changes the text size if it overflows the containing box: jsfiddle.net/0swbytek

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for though, i only want the font to decrease if the text is too long in the sidebar

Comment: Yes ! Exactly! Best i could get so far is just display ellipsis to hide the overflow text